# Office 365 Last Access Timestamp

Tags: outlook, office365, office365api

Complete long shot, but is there a method, either via API or directly in the admin console to view the the last time a user accessed either an email or attachment within the account?

For example:

Tammy receives an email at 3:00 PM

Tammy opens the email at 3:01 PM

Tammy opens the email attachment at 3:02 PM

---

Is is possible to know that Tammy opened the email at 3:01 PM and/or opened the attachment at 3:02 PM?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so.  We do track modifications to items (create time, received time, sent time, last modified time), but I don't think there is way to fetch access times.

Answer (score 0):

No, the best you can do is the last mailbox login time.